# Different Data Types - Signed and Unsigned

Tags: c, operators, equality, integer-promotion

I just executed the following code

```
main()
{
   char a = 0xfb;
   unsigned char b = 0xfb;
   printf("a=%c,b=%c",a,b);
   if(a==b) {
     printf("\nSame");
   }
   else {
     printf("\nNot Same");
   }
}
```

For this code I got the answer as

a=? b=?

Different

Why don't I get Same, and what is the value for a and b?

Comment: read a good C book and learn about memory representation of different data types and difference between `signed` and `unsigned` data types

Comment: "*Different*" really?

Comment: "what is the value for a and b" could have been easily investigated with `printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 cases to consider:

- if the `char` type is unsigned by default, both `a` and `b` are assigned the value `251` and the program will print `Same`.
- if the `char` type is signed by default, which is alas the most common case, the definition `char a = 0xfb;` has implementation defined behavior as `0xfb` (`251` in decimal) is probably out of range for the `char` type (typically `-128` to `127`). Most likely the value `-5` will be stored into `a` and `a == b` evaluates to `0` as both arguments are promoted to `int` before the comparison, hence `-5 == 251` will be false.

The behavior of `printf("a=%c,b=%c", a, b);` is also system dependent as the non ASCII characters `-5` and `251` may print in unexpected ways if at all. Note however that both will print the same as the `%c` format specifies that the argument is converted to `unsigned char` before printing. It would be safer and more explicit to try `printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);`

With gcc or clang, you can try recompiling your program with `-funsigned-char` to see how the behavior will differ.

Comment: Best answer so far as it addresses  that `a = 0xfb;` has implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The line `if (a == b)`... promotes the characters to integers before comparison, so the signedness of the character affects how that happens. The unsigned character 0xFB becomes the integer 251; the signed character 0xFB becomes the integer -5. Thus, they are unequal.

Comment: The signed character became -5 before `if (a == b)`, but at `char a = 0xfb;` time.

Comment: In a manner of speaking, yes. The single byte 0xFB is properly interpreted as -5 even as stored in one byte. Which is why, after the promotion is done, it is physically expanded to 0xFFFFFFFB, while the other is physically expanded to 0x000000FB.

Comment: *Which is why, after the promotion is done, it is physically expanded to 0xFFFFFFFB* maybe, maybe not. The behavior does not depend on the size of `int` nor on the representation of integers in memory. Storing `0xfb` to a signed 8-bit `char` has implementation defined behavior, which in most current architectures will mean storing `-5`, the rest is fully defined on all architectures.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming a lot of things, like 2s-complement binary, and 32-bit ints, etc., that are probably true for the questioner. But as always, C is free to do it a different way if it can.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 4 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, **the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed**....

The usual arithmetic conversions include the integer promotions.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or
>   unsigned int may be used:
>       ...
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **These are called the
>   integer promotions**.58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

So in this equality expression

```
a == b
```

the both operands are converted to the type `int`. The signed operand ( provided that the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char`) is converted to the type `int` by means of propagating the sign bit.

As result the operands have different values due to the difference in the binary representation.

If the type `char` behaves as the type `unsigned char` (for example by setting a corresponding option of the compiler) then evidently the operands will be equal.

Comment: *As result the operands have different values due to the difference in the binary representation.* more precisely due to the difference in the interpretation of the binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

`char` stores from -128 to 127 and `unsigned char` stores from 0 to 255.
and `0xfb` represents 251 in decimal which is beyond the limit of `char a`.